# summarizing a field based on the value of another field in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame DF with four fields: `id, date, feature, value`. I would like to generate a data frame DF2 with three fields: `id, feature, value`, where `value` is the value for the corresponding `id` and `feature` for the latest available `date`. In plyr parlance:

```
DF2 <- ddply(DF, .(id, feature), function(x) c(value(x$value[x$date == max(x$date)]))
```

I am a bit at a loss on how to achieve this with dplyr using group_by and summarize.

Comment: A reproducible data set and desired output would guarantee you 3 answers within 5 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a direct translation of your plyr call in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 = summarise(group_by(DF, id, feature), value=value[which(date == max(date))])
```

Comment: Thanks, worked as a charm. Just a minor modification was needed as  there may be multiple record for a latest date.

Comment: Cool, I've updated my answer to take that into account