# Conditional summarize of groups in dplyr based on date

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I'm an R noob, and trying to perform a summary on a dataset which totals the number of event types for each ID that occurred between events of type 'B' for that ID. Here is a sample to illustrate:

```
id <- c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3')
type <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B')
datestamp <- as.Date(c('2016-06-20','2016-07-16','2016-08-14','2016-07-17'
                       ,'2016-07-18','2016-07-19','2016-07-16','2016-07-19'
                       , '2016-07-21','2016-08-20'))
df <- data.frame(id, type, datestamp)
```

which produces:

```
> df
   id type  datestamp
1   1    A 2016-06-20
2   1    A 2016-07-16
3   1    B 2016-08-14
4   2    A 2016-07-17
5   2    B 2016-07-18
6   2    C 2016-07-19
7   3    A 2016-07-16
8   3    B 2016-07-19
9   3    C 2016-07-21
10  3    B 2016-08-20
```

Any time an event 'B' occurs, I want to know the number of each event type that occurred before that B event, but after any other B events for that ID.
What I would like to end up with is a table like this:

```
  id type B_instance count
1  1    A          1     2
2  2    A          1     1
3  3    A          1     1
4  3    C          2     1
```

In researching, this question came the closest: [summarizing a field based on the value of another field in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722895/summarizing-a-field-based-on-the-value-of-another-field-in-dplyr)

I've been trying to make this work:

```
  df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(id, type) %>%
  summarize(count = count(id[which(datestamp < datestamp[type =='B'])])) %>%
  filter(type != 'B')
```

But it errors out (also, even if it worked, it doesn't account for 2 'B' events in the same ID, like with id=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to create the new group variable `B_instance` by doing `cumsum(type == "B")` and then filter out types that fall behind the last B as well as type B itself, as they will not be counted. Then use `count` to count the occurrence with the group by `id`, `B_instance` and `type`.

```
df %>% 
       group_by(id) %>% 
       # create B_instance using cumsum on the type == "B" condition
       mutate(B_instance = cumsum(type == "B") + 1) %>%    
       # filter out rows with type behind the last B and all B types                 
       filter(B_instance < max(B_instance), type != "B") %>% 
       # count the occurrences of type grouped by id and B_instance
       count(id, type, B_instance) 

# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: id, type [?]

#       id   type B_instance     n
#   <fctr> <fctr>      <dbl> <int>
# 1      1      A          1     2
# 2      2      A          1     1
# 3      3      A          1     1
# 4      3      C          2     1
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you! Out of curiosity, why does cumsum need to be incremented by 1?

Comment: To match the instance count, otherwise it will start from zero, and the result will be like `0,0,0,1` instead of `1,1,1,2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`, grouped by 'id', we get the sequence of the `max` position where 'type' is 'B', find the row index (`.I`), extract that column (`$V1`).  Then, we subset the dataset (`df[i1]`), remove the rows where 'type' is 'B", grouped by 'id', 'type' and the `rleid` of 'type', we get the number of rows as 'count'.

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[seq(max(which(type=="B")))] , by = id]$V1
df[i1][type!="B"][,  .(count = .N), .(id, type, B_instance = rleid(type))]
#   id type B_instance count
#1:  1    A        1     2
#2:  2    A        1     1
#3:  3    A        1     1
#4:  3    C        2     1
```

Comment: This also works very well, thanks. @Psidom's dplyr solution makes more intuitive sense to me. But are there advantages to using a data.table that I'm not aware of? Or just personal preference?

Comment: @feyr Both of them are good packages.  If you want to take advantage of the assignment in place (`:=`), (here that is not done) which data.table does and would be efficient.  However, in this case, psidom's solution will as good as mine or even more elegant.